# How do I vary the lower index of a variable assignment?

Tags: system-verilog

I want to make an assignment to a variable with a variable lower index. This is what I want to do:

```
int i;
logic [63:0] data;

i = someCalculatedNumber;
data[63:(i*8)] = 'h0;
```

I know this won't compile. What is the best method to make this assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to zero-out the LSBs, then this should do it for you

```
data &= '1 << i*8;
```

or more readable

```
data = data & ('1 << i*8);
```

And if that's not exactly what you need, you can still use `'1 << i*8` or its complement as a mask to select the portion of data you want to modify.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a `for` loop:

```
module tb;

int i; 
logic [63:0] data;

initial begin
    data = '1;
    $displayh(data);

    i = 7;
    for (int j=63; j>=(i*8); j--) data[j] = 0;
    $displayh(data);

    i = 2;
    for (int j=63; j>=(i*8); j--) data[j] = 0;
    $displayh(data);
end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
ffffffffffffffff
00ffffffffffffff
000000000000ffff
```

You can wrap the code in a `function`.